# Runner класс cucmber локально запускает все кейсы игнорируя Classpath

Tags: java, junit, cucumber

Окружение тестового проекта:

- java 17
- junit5
- cucumber7

Runner класс:

```
@Cucumber
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@SelectClasspathResource("project/uss/as/play/test/features/smoke/smoke_test.feature")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "project.uss.as.play.test")
public class AtPlayTest {
}
```

```
src  
│
└───main
    │   
    ├───java
    │   │
    │   ├─── project.uss.as.play.test
    │        MyClass.java
    │
    test
    ├───java
    │   │
    │   ├─── project.uss.as.play.test
    │        AtPlayTest =.java
    │
    ├───resources
    │   │
    │   ├─── project.uss.as.play.test
              │
              ├─── features
                   smoke.smoke_test.feature
```

При локальном запуске из идеи запускаются все тесты из папки `features` несмотря на настройку `@SelectClasspathResource("project/uss/as/play/test/features/smoke/smoke_test.feature")`.
Обнаружил, что при запуске формируется структура в папке которой:
`target/test-classes/project/uss/as/play/test/features` лежит и раннер AtPlayTest и все папки с фичами из `test/resources/project/uss/as/play/test/features/` от туда он их и запускает.
Пробовал делать clean и перезапускать, структура формируется в полном объёме. Не смог найти принцип такого запуска для кейсов (генерация в папке target структуры) и не смог решить проблему с локальным запуском определённых кейсов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовал вместо @Cucumber - @Suite